# Can String.Trim() remove characters that a regex \S would have matched?

Tags: c#, regex

Please help me understand if the following is possible:

```
var regexMatch = Regex.Match(inputString, "(\S*\d+\S*|\d)+");

if (regexMatch.Value == String.Empty)
{
    return null;
}
else
{
    var trimmedString = regexMatch.Value.Trim();

    if(trimmmedString != regexMatch.Value)
    {
        //Is there any value for inputString that makes this reachable?
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: If there is a way to reach that line, then I've isolated a bug.  If not, I'm barking up the wrong tree.

Comment: And I'm aware that calling .Trim() on something that's already been Regex matched to have no whitespace doesn't seem to make sense, so I plan to remove the code anyways. I just want to know if it's actually causing my problem and understand if there is a difference in what String.Trim and Regex consider as whitespace.

Comment: I think this is a fair question. It's asking if `.Trim()` removes the same whitespace that a regex containing `\S` would match.

Comment: FWIW, the implementation of `Trim()` looks like this (sorry for format, don't want to post this as an answer): `public static bool IsWhiteSpace(char c)
{
 if (char.IsLatin1(c))
 {
  return char.IsWhiteSpaceLatin1(c);
 }
 return CharUnicodeInfo.IsWhiteSpace(c);
}`

Comment: @TimMedora only for 4.0 and newer, See the "Notes To Callers" [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t97s7bs3.aspx)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Starting with .NET 4.0, `Trim` uses `Char.IsWhiteSpace` method to decide what to trim; [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t809ektx.aspx) lists all characters that would be trimmed. Since the documentation for `\S` does not say that it is using the same list of characters, it is a fair question to ask if there's a mismatch.

One way to find out is an exhaustive search:

```
var ws = new Regex("\\S");
for (char c = '\0'; c != 0xffff; c++) {
    if (char.IsWhiteSpace(c)) {
        var m = ws.Match("" + c);
        if (m.Value.Length != 0) {
            Console.Error.WriteLine("Found a mismatch: {0}", (int)c);
        }
    }
}
```

Running this code produces no result: none of the 26 characters that `char.IsWhitespace` considers whitespace is matched by the `\S` of the regex. Therefore I must conclude that the code protected by the `trimmmedString != regexMatch.Value` condition is unreachable.

As a side note, `regexMatch.Value` can never be `null`: [according to the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.capture.value.aspx),

> If a call to the `Regex.Match` or `Match.NextMatch` method fails to find a match, the value of the returned `Match.Value` property is `String.Empty`.

You can remove the first `if`, or replace it with comparison to `String.Empty`.

Comment: Are you running on .NET 3.5 or 4.0+, `Trim` does not use `Char.IsWhiteSpace` if you are using 3.5 and below, see the "Notes To Callers" [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t97s7bs3.aspx)

Comment: This looks like an authoritative answer compared to mine. I have one question though: How do you obtain the source code of a C# function like `Trim` in this case ? Thanx

Comment: @Sniffer by either [getting the source code from Microsoft](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rscc/) or using a decomplier like [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/) and [dotPeek](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/)

Comment: I'm running on 4.0.  I edited the OP to properly escape non-matches, I only included that statement to illustrate that I don't care about non-matches.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Thank you. I didn't know they release the source code into the public.

Comment: @Sniffer I did not look at the source code -- the info about the inner workings of the `Trim()` function comes straight from the documentation of the method (see the [note to callers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t97s7bs3.aspx) section).

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Thank you, I noticed that after posting the comment.

Answer (score 4):

Your code is a bit questionable, but I will answer the question of whether `String.Trim()` is equivalent to using `\s` to remove leading and trailing white-spaces or not.

**They are equivalent from .NET Framework 4.0**

- From .NET 4.0, [`String.Trim()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t97s7bs3.aspx) will remove leading and trailing characters which make [`Char.IsWhitespace()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t809ektx.aspx) returns **true**.

  `Char.IsWhitespace()` returns **true** for characters in [categories Zl, Zp, Zs](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/index.htm), as per description in the documentation, and also for `\t`, `\n`, `\v`, `\f`, `\r`, `\x85`.

  Note that there seems to be some discrepancies. According to [fileformat.info](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Zs/list.htm), `U+00A0 NO-BREAK SPACE` belongs to `Zs` category, but MSDN doesn't put it in the list of Space Separator in `Char.IsWhitespace()`'s documentation. Testing reveals that `\s` matches `U+00A0`, which means `U+00A0` is one of the characters in `\p{Z}` category.
- According to the page [Character Classes in Regular Expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z.aspx#WhitespaceCharacter), `\s` is equivalent to `[\f\n\r\t\v\x85\p{Z}]`. The `Z` category currently consists of 3 sub-categories: Zs, Zl, Zp.

**They are not equivalent prior to .NET 4.0**

According to `String.Trim()` documentation:

> Because of this change, the Trim method in the .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 and earlier versions removes two characters, `ZERO WIDTH SPACE (U+200B)` and `ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE (U+FEFF)`, that the Trim method in the .NET Framework 4 and later versions does not remove.
>
> In addition, the Trim method in the .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 and earlier versions does not trim three Unicode white-space characters: `MONGOLIAN VOWEL SEPARATOR (U+180E)`, `NARROW NO-BREAK SPACE (U+202F)`, and `MEDIUM MATHEMATICAL SPACE (U+205F)`.

To put it simply, `String.Trim()` considers a **different set of characters** for removal in .NET versions prior to 4.0.

The specification for `\s` in regular expression stays the same from .NET 1.1.

Comment: The code wasn't originally mine, I just wanted to isolate the part I thought _might_ be causing a bug.

Answer (score 3):

[dasblinkenlight answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/18645108/1) is wrong, the behavior changed from .NET 3.5 to .NET 4.0., see the ["Notes to Callers" here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t97s7bs3.aspx). Changing his code slightly so it actually uses `Trim()` the test finds no matches for .NET 4.0 but finds two matches for .NET 3.5

```
public class Program
{

    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var ws = new Regex("\\S");
        for (char c = '\0'; c != 0xffff; c++)
        {
            if (new String(c, 1).Trim().Length == 0)
            {
                var m = ws.Match("" + c);
                if (m.Value.Length != 0)
                {
                    Console.Error.WriteLine("Found a mismatch: {0}", (int)c);
                }
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("done");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

}

//Output running in .NET 3.5:
//Found a mismatch: 8203
//Found a mismatch: 65279
//done


//Output running in .NET 4.0:
//done
```

Comment: That's nice to know! OP [did indicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18644845/can-string-trim-remove-characters-that-a-regex-s-would-have-matched/18645108?noredirect=1#comment27453425_18645108) that he's running on .NET 4.0, though.

Comment: I did eventually indicate that I am running 4.0, but I do appreciate the extra effort to be exhaustive on behalf of others who might be stuck with an older version.